# Network devices bandwidth monitoring and graphing with open source components?

Tags: nagios, snmp, ganglia, mrtg

We can use ganglia to monitor metrics on servers, but it does not seem to be an option for network gear monitoring.

To monitor bandwidth of a switch, we need to either poll the port through SNMP protocol or somehow talk to sFlow/netflow agent running on the the switch/router. Any open source based option on the table? MRTG sounds a good out of box solution option, but I really wish I could use nagios or ganglia if possible because I am using them right now anyway (and I hope not to introduce another thing into the equation)

Comment: Stanford has a curated list of resource they maintain http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html

Answer (score 1):

have you try [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) there is plugin for [netflow](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:flowview) (honestly i never use this plugin), maybe you want to take a look (http://gregsowell.com/?p=610)